# Media queries strange behaviour

Tags: media-queries

I've got following media-queries rules:

1. `@media only screen and (max-width: 854px), only screen and
   (max-device-width: 854px)` (for devices <= 854px)
2. `@media only screen and (min-width: 855px), only screen and
   (min-device-width: 855px)` (for devices > 854px)

It's strange but Chrome (and may be other browsers) use this rules at the same time (when width is 800px for example) (check screen). What's wrong?
[image: stange media-queries behaviour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are falling back to the same rule because you are using `device-width`, the condition for `device-width` targets your device's physical width so if that condition is satisfied then that's the only rule that will be applied (regardless if you resize your browser to any width). Remove both the `device-width` conditions from your media queries, this should solve your issue.

To learn more about the difference between `device-width` and `width`, refer to this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Suvi.
I was testing media-query rules by changing width of browser (not by changing screen resolution). Because my browser width was less then 854px following rule was applied - `@media only screen and (max-width: 854px)`. Because my screen resolution was more then 854px following rule was applied - `only screen and (min-device-width: 855px)`